# Portable Linux Compiled Executable with OpenGL / Mesa3D

Tags: linux, opengl, executable, mesa

I have been reading up on cross platform development with OpenGL for games. We are looking at developing a game which will be available to Linux users too. I have however come across something I am not quite getting my head around.

How to create a portable linux executable? Specifically how to get the various different versions of OpenGL / Mesa3D to work in one (or more) executable file/s (we do not want to distribute the source).

Over on Linux Questions http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/hardware-acceleration-using-opengl-and-x11-876634/ someone goes in to detail on how Mesa3D / OpenGL work but what I am struggling to see is how I would go about using each distro's version of Mesa3D within my compiled executable (not even sure if it is possible).

From what I can tell I am required to dynamically link parts of the application together on each users machine, possibly through the use of an installer? If this is the case can we part compile the program and link at runtime for Mesa3D / OpenGL much like OpenGL's dll's can do on Windows?

Comment: You can use shared objects (`.so`), which are similar to `.dll`s. The recomended method would be to pre-compile "packages" (i.e. `.deb`, `.rpm`) which users can install easily. These packages can declare dependencies on other packages, i.e specific versions of a library, which will then be installed automatically. There should be tons of tutorials for packaging out there.

Comment: yeah, you just need to link to `libGL.so.1`

Comment: Save yourself the hassle, and use [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @BrettHale: GLEW does manage only the extensions. OP is asking about OpenGL itself.

Comment: This part of the questions is also correct! It's just I can't mark it answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just link your executable dynamically against `libGL.so` and be done with it. The binary interface of that is common among all implementations of OpenGL.

> From what I can tell I am required to dynamically link parts of the application together on each users machine, possibly through the use of an installer?

Not you do the linking and neither does a installer. The dynamic linking happens automatically when the executable is loaded. Dynamic linking is how DLLs get loaded in Windows and the *nix counterpart Shared Objects (`.so`) on *nix.

When building your program, you add the option `-lGL` to the linker command line and it will add a dynamic linkage entry to `libGL.so` to the exeutable. That you can then redistribute. When the program gets started on the target system, the dynamic linker will locate the libGL.so and load it.